# How to connect arduino with shield correctly?

Tags: arduino

What is the good and not permanent way to attach arduino with shield?

I try to attach it with sparkfun usb shield via pin , but sometime it did not read unless i apply some pressure on it, then it will read and the usb host shield light will on.

[USB host shield](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9947) 
http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9947

[Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno)

[image]

Comment: In order to help you need more detail in your questions. Schematics, pictures, links to the supposed shield would all help.

Comment: updated , anymore info i should put?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might have a bad solder joint. Without anything else connected I would check all of the traces from your usb host shield to each header pin. If those all check out try the same on the uno. You may also just want to consider doing a re-solder (on the header pins of the shield) and try again.

When you are applying pressure it may be moving the pins slightly and making contact.

Also make sure the shield is completely seated in the uno headers and that the UNO powers on w/o the shield attached.

Comment: Any other way i can solve this except to re-solder? It a shield that i brought. Any accessories that use to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: i tried with other pins but it still have problem. I believe it is the 5v pin because when i did not apply pressure , the light on the usb host did not on

Comment: If you bought it assembled you could always return it. Sparkfun is pretty good for helping with stuff like this. You can call them and ask for tech support. I'm not sure they will tell you anything different, but in the end they my send you a new shield. Soldering the header pins should be pretty straight forward. It is a great place to start learning as the pins are right at the edge and the solder mask is pretty good at keeping you from causing shorts.